pycharm-community-2024.2.2 shows double param in documentation
When adding the docstring to my function, the params are show twice in the documentation.
I'm using reStructuredText.
This is the code I have:
def get_table_columns(self, name, names_only):
    """

    :param name: 
    :param names_only: 
    :return: 
    """

This is the documentation result:

Why does this happen?
